# How to save geolocation details in local variables to use it later

Tags: typescript, geolocation, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am pretty noob to Nativescript (with anngular2/typescript). My use case is to track users location using nativescript geolocation plugin and save the results (such as latitude and longitude) for the later usage. Below is my sample code :

```
export class AppComponent {
    public latitude: number;
    public longitude: number;

 public constructor() 
 {
      this.updateLocation();
      this.getWeather(this.latitude ,this.longitude);
 }

private getDeviceLocation(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            geolocation.enableLocationRequest().then(() => {
                geolocation.getCurrentLocation({desiredAccuracy:3,updateDistance:10,timeout: 20000}).then(location => {
                    resolve(location);

                }).catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                });
            });
        });
    }

 public updateLocation() {
        this.getDeviceLocation().then(result => {
// i am saving data here for later usage 
            this.latitude = result.latitude;
            this.longitude = result.longitude;
        }, error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

public getWeather(latitude:number,longitude:number){
// do stuff with lat and long 
}
}
```

But i am not able to pass the value of latitude and longitude to getWeather method.It comes as undefined.What i am doing wrong? I know the workaround : by calling getWeather right inside from updateLocation where these values are available and get this thing working but somehow I feel it is not an appropriate way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: the `getWeather()` function will fire before the `updateLocation()` method has chance to finish so the values will be undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you think is "not an appropriate way" is actually the appropriate way; your `this.updateLocation()` function is async (Promise), so the line below (`this.getWeather(this.latitude ,this.longitude)`) runs before `this.latitude` and `this.longitude` are initialized.

You'll want to invoke `getWeather` when those are initialized, and that's exactly when the Promise returns in `updateLocation`..